# Centos 7 + Plesk, Cant access control panel

Tags: centos, vps, plesk

I am in this horrible situation. I have tried several ways to get my VPS server properly to work. 
My problem is that my server anru.info is pointing to https://server1:8443/ instead of [IP]:8443 or anru.info:8443 when i try to access the Plesk control panel

What could the problem be? I have tried to change the Hostname, edit the host files, restarted server. I am clueless.

Answer (score 0):

try accessing it via:
http://server1:8880

Accessing via non secure.

or via you actual ip address insteadof hostname

Comment: OP doesn't want to access http://server1:8443, suggesting to access http://server1:8880 is not an answer when its clearly mentioned anru.info should redirect to IP:8443 or anru.info:8443